# How do I use C++11 on Mac?

Tags: eosiocpp, c++

I tried the [hello world](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract) sample contract, and when it came time to compile, I got this error:

```
hello.cpp:10:10: error: expected ']'
                [[eosio:action]]
                       ^
                       ]
hello.cpp:10:5: warning: unknown attribute 'eosio' ignored [-Wunknown-attributes]
                [[eosio:action]]
                  ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

I fixed it by using the GNU-style attribute syntax [mentioned here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt#difference-from-old-abi-generator). However, I'd like to stick to the intended C++11 syntax, or at least know what the tradeoffs are for using the GNU syntax. If I follow the C++11 syntax, I'm supposing I need to upgrade my compiler to accept C++11 syntax? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

To use this syntax, you need to be compiling with the latest version of [`eosio.cdt`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt).
When you build and compile `eosio.cdt`, it will install the appropriate `clang` compiler for you, and `eosio-cpp` will be called with all of the appropriate flags.

Also, in your particular case, your attributes are missing a colon, it should say `[[eosio::action]]`, not `[[eosio:action]]`.